# How to set focus on show, where ngIf bind change to true?

Tags: angular

I am trying to do editable cell:

```
  <ng-template pCellDef [column]="field.property" let-row="row" let-inEdit="false">
    <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%" (click)="inEdit=true" (blur)="inEdit=false">
    <div *ngIf="!inEdit">
      {{row[field.property]}}
    </div>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="inEdit" class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row[field.property]">
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

It is working well, the final thing that I need to do , is to set **focus** on input, that let the user to type.

So, there is a way to do that, without exclude the input to component?

something like  `(onShow)="this.focus()"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **autofocus** :

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="inEdit" class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row[field.property]" autofocus>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hey, autofocus works only once in a input fiels. i have recreated your stackbiltx and posred answer in yor new question. Please have a look and let me know. I replaced bla with a button

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ElementRef` here is the example

**HTML**

```
 <ng-template pCellDef [column]="field.property" let-row="row" let-inEdit="false">
    <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%" (click)="inEdit=true" (blur)="inEdit=false">
    <div *ngIf="!inEdit">
      {{row[field.property]}}
    </div>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="inEdit" class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="row[field.property]" #inputRef>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('inputRef') inputRefData : ElementRef

customFocus() {
  this.inputRefData.nativeElement.focus();
}
```